# Delete All Rows With Errors in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a VBA code and part of the code is needed to delete all the rows in the sheet where the text in the column "J" is "#N/A". I have written a code but but I get a Type mismatch error when debugging it.

Here is the code

```
Dim i As Long
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If Cells(i, 10) = "#N/A" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```

Comment: You need to trap the error N/A is display, the contents of the cell is something like Error 2042, so use IsError

Comment: `If worksheetfunction.IsError(Cells(i, 10)) then...` as @Nathan_Sav said

Comment: I tried your suggestion your suggestion and it does seem to work but talking ages to execute. I guess this is because the file has more than 10000 rows.

This is what I did


`Dim i As Long
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If worksheetfunction.IsError(Cells(i, 10)) Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i`

Comment: Turn your calculations off at the beginning and turn them back on at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the **xlSpecialCellsValue** constant as **xlErrors** to quickly identify all cells in column J with errors. It wasn't disclosed whether the cells were formulas or typed constants so I've added code to examine both through the [xlCellType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) types.

```
Sub del_error_rows()
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        On Error Resume Next
        With .Columns(10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        With .Columns(10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors)
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

The `On Error Resume Next` is necessary in case there are no cells with that particular error configuration. In that case, the SpecialCells would be `Nothing` and you must bypass any error thrown from attempting to handle nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If Cells(i, 10).Text = "#N/A" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```